# Embedding XML directive in XML body using Java Client connecting to WCF service

Tags: java, xml, wcf, cxf, spring-ws

Our Java proxy needs to communicate with a WCF based ESB/Service.

It looks like the service expects the XML payload to look like:

```
<xmlRequest><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><payload/></xmlRequest>
```

Is there anyway to slip this past SAAJ, so that the WCF service will get what it needs ?

**Details**

- I know this is illegal, but their service is in production and I am trying to replace our DataPower appliance.
- Our current security proxy, iteration #3, is DOM based.

As expected when I used XSLT to add the XML directive SAAJ indicated an error.

- I have tried escaping the XML directive using :

  ```
       CDATA to escape the XML directive.

       CDATA to escape the entire payload.

       Massaging the directive to look like valid XML 
       Using HTML escape characters.
  ```
- Ws-Security is used: spring-ws + WSS4J so we can't modify the payload at the http level outbound once its been secured.
- We modified spring-ws for a reasonable use case but I don't believe modifying wss4j for this special case would be maintainable.

**Options**

It looks like the most maintable option is to switch to simple CXF Stream based approach, with WSS4J.

**Due diligance**
This probably sounds familar but before I can move on to using CXF, management wants to be sure there is not a clever trick to escaping that XML directive.

Any comments including good natured chiding are welcome !

Comment: It turns out that even though I was asking for the raw output from the applicance I was using to capturing the data it ended up pretty printing the XML payload anyway. So the XML payload was html encoded so it wasn't sending "<..." it was sending "&lt;..."  I was inturn using that input to feed SoapUI and send the message, which didn't represent what was actually geting sent, thus causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The  part is a processing instruction. As per
https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi and https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd you can see that the beginning of the document is a prolog, and for processing instructions during the document the PITarget may be anything BUT xml. So your document can no longer be parsed by a compliant parser.

If you believe the above is what the other side requires, try to serialize your document into a text node and add that as content of xmlRequest. It would looke like

```
<xmlRequest>&lt;?xml ...
```

Alternatively you could try to serialize your document into a CDATA section (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) but for me it feels just similarly wrong as for you. And you already tried my suggestions.

After all the XMLdecl is optional (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-prolog). Have you tried to omit the xml declaration using this in your XSLT?

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

If all that does not work, how do other clients send the data? How do their messages look like?

Comment: Yes I knew this was a processing instruction, which is why I was indicating it was illegal in the middle.

Comment: Good we agree on that. So how do other clients actually use that service? I doubt they can send illegal data if you cannot.

Comment: See comment made above.